# Send Multiple Point Cloud Data in one Message ROS

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

As we already know, if we want to send multiple value in one message toward ROS node, we can use std_msgs/MultiArray. 
How about point cloud?, Is there any idea how to send multiple point cloud data in one message ROS?, Thank you very much for your answers.

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Since a point cloud is just a collection of points (see: [Documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html)), you could collect points of multiple point clouds to a single point cloud.

**Option 2:**

Define your own message to collect multiple point clouds. This *PointCloudCollection.msg* could look like:

```
#Header (optional)
Header header
#Point clouds
sensor_msgs/PointCloud[] point_clouds
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help