# Publisher Message Type Problem in ROS, publishing point cloud array

Tags: ros

I am trying to load point clouds and publish an array of the point clouds using a ROS publisher.

my code snippet shown below.

```
std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> loadInstancePointClouds(const std::string& directory) {
    std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> point_clouds;

    // Load point clouds from files in directory
    for (fs::directory_iterator itr(directory); itr != fs::directory_iterator(); ++itr) {
        // Check if file is a PCD file
        if (fs::is_regular_file(itr->path()) && itr->path().extension() == ".pcd")
        {
            // Load point cloud data from file
            sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 point_cloud_2;
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> point_cloud_1;
            //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> point_cloud;
            if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile(itr->path().string(), point_cloud_1) == -1) {
                ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Failed to load point cloud file " << itr->path().string());
            }
            else {
                pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(point_cloud_1, point_cloud_2);
                point_clouds.push_back(point_cloud_2);
            }
        }
    }

    return point_clouds;
}
void publishInstancePointClouds(const std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>& point_clouds,
                        ros::Publisher& publisher) {
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg;
  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg.header.frame_id = "map";
  for (const auto& point_cloud : point_clouds) {
    msg.data.push_back(point_cloud);
  }
  publisher.publish(msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Initialize ROS and create a node handle
    ros::init(argc, argv, "point_cloud_loader");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    // Load point clouds from directory
    std::string directory = "./results/clusters";
    std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> point_clouds = loadInstancePointClouds(directory);

    // Publish point clouds as Float32MultiArray
    ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>>("instances", 10);
                               // nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray>("instances", 10);
    publishInstancePointClouds(point_clouds, publisher);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the error as follows:

```
 error: ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >’
  120 |     return M::__s_getMD5Sum().c_str();
```

and I am not sure if this is a problem with appending to the wrong member of the msg, or wrong msg type etc?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting might be due to this line:

```cpp
    ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>>("instances", 10);
```

the template for the advertise function is based on a ROS message type and not a C++ type. So if you want an array of pointclouds, you will have to define a custom message type and use it there. Alternatively, if you are only interested in the points, you can aggregate all the points in a single pointcloud and send that one pointcloud.

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60596616/6619949